# Load SQL Data on Start

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I was wondering if there is any possible way for me to load my data in my database in my listview right when I start my application. I'm currently using a button which does the same job but it doesn't look that good really. It's a very lazy way on how to solve this problem.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add you loading code in the onstart() method and can initialize the listview there itself

Answer (score 0):

I have a JSP-Servlet application doing the same thing on my `/index` (index.jsp) page.
It loads a list of Oracle DB records in a table.

My web.xml has

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Whenever I access `/index` route via my browser, a GET request is fired which is handled by `doGet()` method in `IndexServlet.java`

Here you can write your SQL code to fetch all the records and the data can be sent back to the JSP page via the `ServletResponse`

**Method 2 -**

You can use an AJAX request from the front-end

```
$(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: '<your URL/route>',
      type: 'GET',
      data:{
         //code
      },
      success: function(data){
         //code
      }
   });
});
```

This script will run after the DOM is loaded completely.